# goto from out of function in C#

Tags: c#, scope, goto

Is it possible to make a goto to a label outside of the current function in C#?

For example on the load event, I want to goto to a certain part inside the onSubmitButton_click event. Is this possible even if it's not using goto?

Comment: i dont think its possible.. since it out of context already.. [someone ever asked on msdn forum regarding out of scope goto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b5b8072e-86ae-4744-88bf-f8a27676a639/use-of-goto-but-outside-of-scope?forum=csharpgeneral).. and yes, thats not possible. better to create another method to deal with such cases.

Comment: Maybe you just move this "certain part" from `onSubmitButton_click` to a separate private method, and then call it from both events? `goto` is a procedural languages stuf, but we are object-oriented.

Comment: @vasily.sib - "`goto` is a procedural languages stuf, but we are object-oriented." - that's not technically correct. C# is a procedural language that uses OO. Methods/Properties are still procedural.

Comment: Please show us the full code so that we can give you a proper answer. Code it like you think it would work if `goto` would magically work like you want.

Comment: @Enigmativity, completely agree. What I mean is that I'm ready to see a `goto` in `C` code and I know what it will do, but I have no idea how it can work in `C#`

Comment: @vasily.sib - It's a while since I coded in C but I thought it was the same as in C#.

Comment: @Enigmativity definitely not the same. `C` not OO, so when you use `goto` it compiles to some kind of JUMP instruction and you absolutly sure where execution will continue. Imaging if `C#` have a `goto`. What if label, that I want go to is placed in not static method of another class? How CLR will handle this? In what instance of that class, method will be called? What if there none instance constructed yet? What I mean is: in OOP `goto` is pointless.

Comment: @vasily.sib - Can you just from one procedure to another in C? I thought it was just within the one procedure. If that's the case then C# is just the same. If not, I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a case of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You're asking how to use `goto` to achieve your goal, when `goto` is not what you want to use to achieve that goal.

As vasily.sib points out in the comments, what you most likely want to do is to extract your common code into a private method and call that from both of your handlers. Depending on what you want to achieve, it may prove to be difficult. If you provide a code example of what exactly you're doing, we will have a better chance of actually helping you solve this issue.

As a rule of thumb, if you want to use `goto` in C# for anything, just don't. There might be legitimate reasons to use `goto`, but your question reveals that you're still fairly inexperienced, so you're not likely to hit those yet. I've been working professionally with C# for a few years now and so far I never actually needed to use it.